# How to rewrite SQL joins into window functions?

Tags: postgresql, join, window-functions, vertica

Database is HP Vertica 7 or PostgreSQL 9.

```
create table test (
id int,
card_id int,
tran_dt date,
amount int
);

insert into test values (1, 1, '2017-07-06', 10);
insert into test values (2, 1, '2017-06-01', 20);
insert into test values (3, 1, '2017-05-01', 30);
insert into test values (4, 1, '2017-04-01', 40);
insert into test values (5, 2, '2017-07-04', 10);
```

Of the payment cards used in the last 1 day, what is the maximum amount charged on that card in the last 90 days.

```
select t.card_id, max(t2.amount) max
from test t
join test t2 on t2.card_id=t.card_id and t2.tran_dt>='2017-04-06'
where t.tran_dt>='2017-07-06'
group by t.card_id
order by t.card_id;
```

Results are correct

```
card_id    max
-------    ---
1          30
```

I want to rewrite the query into sql window functions.

```
select card_id, max(amount) over(partition by card_id order by tran_dt range between '60 days' preceding and current row) max
from test
where card_id in (select card_id from test where tran_dt>='2017-07-06')
order by card_id;
```

But result set does not match, how can this be done?

Test data here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/db317/1

Comment: Firstly, Postgres and Vertica are two very different things. Secondly, why do you expect results from two very different queries to be the same?

Answer (score 2):

I can't try PostgreSQL, but in Vertica, you can apply the ANSI standard OLAP window function.

But you'll need to nest two queries: The window function only returns sensible results if it has all rows that need to be evaluated in the result set.

But you only want the row from '2017-07-06' to be displayed.

So you'll have to filter for that date in an outer query:

```
WITH olap_output AS (
  SELECT 
    card_id
  , tran_dt
  , MAX(amount) OVER (
      PARTITION BY card_id
      ORDER BY tran_dt
      RANGE BETWEEN '90 DAYS' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS the_max
  FROM test
)
SELECT
  card_id
, the_max
FROM olap_output
WHERE tran_dt='2017-07-06'
;

card_id|the_max
      1|     30
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, PostgreSQL Window function doesn't support bounded `range preceding` thus `range between '90 days' preceding` won't work.  It does support bounded `rows preceding` such as `rows between 90 preceding`, but then you would need to assemble a time-series query similar to the following for the Window function to operate on the time-based rows:

```
SELECT c.card_id, t.amount, g.d as d_series
FROM generate_series(
  '2017-04-06'::timestamp, '2017-07-06'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval
) g(d)
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT distinct card_id from test ) c
LEFT JOIN test t ON t.card_id = c.card_id and t.tran_dt = g.d
ORDER BY c.card_id, d_series
```

For what you need (based on your question description), I would stick to using `group by`.